Getting heap storage with proper alignment in C++ for overaligned type
In some use case, you'll need to allocate storage before creating objects inside this storage.
Then in order to create these objects, you may need to use placement new:
T *pobj = new(pstorage);

yet you have to provide a properly aligned pstorage.
AFAIU following code provides no guarantee for over-aligned types.
// properly aligned heap storage to hold N contiguous T objects
unsigned char *storage = new unsigned char[N*sizeof(T)];

operator new overloads for overaligned type don't seem to be usable explicitly (https://stackoverflow.com/a/78679166/21691539).
The simplest solution I found so far was:
// in the spirit of std::aligned_storage
// can be on the stack or on the heap
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Storage {
    alignas(T) unsigned char storage[N * sizeof(T)];
}

auto *wrapped_storage = new Storage<T,N>;
auto *storage = wrapped_storage.storage;

But it works only if the number of objects is known at compile-time.
What would be the proper way to get a raw storage suitably aligned of over-aligned types?

From C++17 on:
// properly aligned heap storage to hold N contiguous T objects
unsigned char *storage = std::aligned_alloc(alignas(T),N*sizeof(T));
...
// releasing memory
std::free(storage);


Snippet for creating a non implicit-lifetime object at position i:
// placement-new
new(storage+i*sizeof(T)) T(<constructor args>);
...
// destroying non-trivially destructible object is mandatory before releasing storage
T* toDelete = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(storage+i*sizeof(T)));
toDelete->~T(); // destroy object but don't deallocate memory

This is only a low level example and smarter implementation using smart pointer would be better.
